# Kohana Query builder JOIN -> ON

Tags: mysql

while translating my query in Kohana query builder syntax i run in to some problems.
So i have the fallowing query :

```
select distinct fr.freelancer_id from freelancers_skills as fr
join freelancers_areas as f_a on f_a.area_id in (7,8,1,2)
where fr.skill_id in (5,6)
```

and while doing so in Kohana its something like :

```
DB::select ( 'fr.freelancer_id' )->distinct ( TRUE )
                            ->from ( array('freelancers_skills','fr') )
                            ->join(array('freelancers_areas','f_a'))
                              ->on('f_a.area_id','IN',array(1,2,3))
                            ->where ('fr.skill_id','in',array(5,6))
                            ->execute();
```

but i am getting an error saying that ->on('f_a.area_id','IN',array(1,2,3) it has an syntax error.
Anyone that can help me with this one?

Comment: shouldn't you join freelancers_areas with freelancers_skills? As it stands, you just filter out the results by area, but you don't join the recordsets.

Comment: i am trying to run a query that gets :
ALL FREELANCERS THAT HAVE skills [ skills_id ] OR AREAS [area_id ]
So there might be a freelancer that has some areas but doesn't have some skills and the other way around

Comment: Yeah, so your query is wrong. The model itself too probably, but it's hard to tell without seeing it